# Android Studio: Make a Button go from an Activity to a Specific Tab in another Activity which was created with the Tabbed Template?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, tabs

My application was first created with the Tabbed Activity template given by Android studio. I have 5 tabs within that activity. Each of these tabs has a button that I can get to go to a new activity that I have created. I cannot, however get a button on the new activity to go back to the tab I first clicked the button on.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private Button eventPage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.deleteAccount) {
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.logOut){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

**SectionsPagerAdapter.java**

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private int noOfTabs;

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
     //Returning the current tabs
    switch(position) {
        case 0:
            Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
            return tab2;
        case 2:
            Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();
            return tab3;
        case 3:
            Tab4 tab4 = new Tab4();
            return tab4;
        case 4:
            Tab5 tab5 = new Tab5();
            return tab5;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 5;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "Profile";
        case 1:
            return "Connections";
        case 2:
            return "Suggestions";
        case 3:
            return "Events";
        case 4:
            return "Groups";
    }
    return null;
}}
```

**CreateEventActivity**

```
public class CreateEventActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_event);
}}
```

The button that I would like to add functionality to is on the activity_create_event.xml and I need it to take the user back to the Main Activity in the 4th tab.

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  Please take a moment to review our [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: pressing back button will take you to the activity in stack i.e it will take you to previous activity

Comment: @arjun_sna I don't have a back button in my toolbar

Comment: call `onBackPressed()` in `onClick()` method of the button